# reCAPTCHA Error Invalid domain for site key on localhosted website

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I am trying to render Recaptcha V2 Enterprise with site-key from other website on my local host. Normally, you will get error “invalid domain”  if you are using external site-key

I needed it for manual solving and getting “solve-token”, and then post token to origin website by request. I am able to render, solve and get token only by changing my DNS redirect in hosts file, but i am unable to reach origin website to post token cause it conflicts with my local website. Is there any way to render Recaptcha at local website without changing redirection and getting error “invalid domain”?